# Excel Vba Loop , not running properly

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

guys i'm currently working on some excel vba , and i came across with a problem , i've been trying to set my loop to run all the way until the end but for some reason it's not working on this function.
Or at least not running as i need it.

```
Private Sub validar()

Dim src As Workbook
Dim last as long, k As long
Dim ref  As String, nac  As String, npc As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


folha = estadoform.Label1.Caption
lastnum = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
num = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Cells(lastnum, 6)

' ABRIR EXCEL
Set src = Workbooks.Open("U:\Mecânica\Produção\OEE\OEE ( FULL LOG )\OEEalerta.xlsx", True, False)

Sheets("alerta").Select
last = Workbooks("OEEalerta.xlsx").Sheets("alerta").Range(" A10000").End(xlUp).Row

For k = 1 To last
    ref = .Cells(k, 2)
    npc = .Cells(k, 4)
    nac = .Cells(k, 5)

    If num = ref And (nac < npc) Then

        nac = nac + 1

    End If

Next k

ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

'SAVES FILE USING THE VARIABLE BOOKNAME AS FILENAME
src.Save

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS

' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
src.Close True             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What is happenning on your code? 
Also what is "num" you didn t define it? And nac = nac+1 is useless in your code as you are redefining nac in the next loop right after

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` so that it tells you which line has the error?

Comment: It does not gives me any error but , for exemple ref should be equal to num but that's not happening. Num is giving the wright output , but ref is giving another number from another line

Comment: Like Pierre44 already mentioned:  nac = Cells(k, 5) ==> nac = nac +1  and then nac = Cells(k, 5)  again. Put  nac = .Cells(k, 5) before For k = 1 to last

Comment: Ref get its cell row from the k (From the loop).could you please provide image from your sheet with guidelines?

Comment: @EvR if i do that then i get na object defined error.

Comment: You just added points before  Cells(k, 5), but I don't see an With, End With statement

Comment: It was not me , it's and editred version of my original question

Comment: Basicaly i need to open a file and filter it to match my criteria and go to the last collum and do cell = cell +1

Comment: You use src.save to save changes to the "source" WorkBook. But you never update it. Aren't you trying to do "Then .Cells(k, 5) = nac + 1" instead of "Then nac = nac + 1"? This would update the values in the Workbook instead of just modifying the procedure's internal variable.

Comment: Have you done basic debugging like stepping through? None of us know what your data looks like, what your results are or what they should be. Read [mcve].

Comment: Also, shouldn't nac be defined as Long, instead of as String? I guess that is the case, since you are adding 1 to nac.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'll be guessing here.

Firstly, always try to give meaningful names to your variables. This is to help clarify your intentions.

Also, don't forget to qualify all members, like Cells(), you're accessing. This is very important, since it can change the your program's behaviour. So, I would write src.Cells(...) instead of just Cells(....)

You don't need to select a WorkSheet to read/write to it.

Use Option Explicit at the beginning of your modules. This way you'll have to explicitly declare all of your variables, and avoid some common errors like mistyping the name of a variable.

As I commented, you are saving changes but you never change the source workbook.
Also, you are performing some algebraic operations on String values!

So, here comes my guess:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub validar()

    Dim folha           As Long                 ' sheet number
    Dim src             As Workbook             ' a workbook from which alerts are being read
    Dim lastRow         As Long                 ' last row with content in a worksheet
    Dim alertNum        As Long                 ' Alert number being updated
    Dim k               As Long                 ' counter
    Dim ref             As String               ' reference of the alert 
    Dim nac             As Long                 ' nac ?
    Dim npc             As Long                 ' npc ?

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    folha = CLng(estadoform.Label1.Caption)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha)
        lastRow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        alertNum = .Cells(lastRow, 6)
    End With

    ' ABRIR EXCEL
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("U:\Mecânica\Produção\OEE\OEE ( FULL LOG )\OEEalerta.xlsx", True, False)
    With src.Sheets("alerta")
        lastRow = .Range(" A10000").End(xlUp).Row
        For k = 1 To lastRow
            ref = .Cells(k, 2)
            npc = .Cells(k, 4)
            nac = .Cells(k, 5)

            If ref = alertNum And (nac < npc) Then .Cells(k, 5) = nac + 1    ' update where the filter conditions are met
        Next k
    End With

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT
    'SAVES FILE USING THE VARIABLE BOOKNAME AS FILENAME
    src.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE (since it has already been saved)
    Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```